# Show that $\text{Cov}(AY)=A\text{Cov}(Y)A^T$

Tags: vectors, expected-value, variance, covariance

Let $Y$ be a $p$-dimensional random vector $\mathbb{E}|Y|^2\lt \infty$, and $A$ be a $q\times p$ deterministic matrix. Show that

$$\text{Cov}(AY)=A\text{Cov}(Y)A^T$$

My solution:

$$\text{Cov}(AY)\mathbb{E}\biggr[(AY-\mathbb{E}[AY])(AY-\mathbb{E}[AY)^T\biggr]=\mathbb{E}\biggl[(AY-A\mathbb{E}[Y])(AY-A\mathbb{E}[Y])^T\biggl]=\mathbb{E}\biggl[A(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^TA^T\biggr]=A\mathbb{E}\biggl[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^T\biggr]A^T=A\text{Cov}(Y)A^T$$

Would this solution be correct?

Also, the answer to this question states the following:

Write $(AY)_i=\sum_jA_{ji}Y_j$ and argue from the definition of covariance.

**First of all, isn't it supposed to be $(AY)_i=\sum_j(A)_{ij}Y_j$  (indices i and j were not in order)?**

I attempted to solve the problem vie their method also:

We have that $(AY)_i=\sum^p_{j=1}(A)_{ij}Y_j = a_i^TY$, where $a_i=(A_{i1},A_{i2},...,A_{ip})^T$ i.e., the rows of $A$.

So, similarly as in my first method:

$$\text{Cov}(a_i^TY)=a_i^T\text{Cov}(Y)a_i$$

But I found that $$(A\text{Cov}A^T)_{ij}=\sum^p_{r=1}a_{ir}\Sigma_{ir}a_{jr}$$

Well now I'm confused now.

I don't know if I overcomplicated it, or I didn't start doing it correctly from the beginning. If you could tell me if my first method is correct and how I went wrong with the second method, I would appreciate that a lot.

Comment: setting aside a typo, the first solution looks fine

Comment: @user8675309 thank you for reviewing it!